# Scraping text that unhides on Button click with beautifulsoup and python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

So I am trying to scrape with the following URL:
[Website](https://en.indonetwork.co.id/company/surrama-groups)

The page has some hidden text that unlocks after a click.
Their HTML code is also hidden and unhides after button clicks.

##### Before click:

[image: Before Click Image]

##### After click:

[image: After click Image]

How can I scrape this text?

BeautifulSoup doesn't work on this text.

Answer (score 0):

If you open dev tools and click those buttons, you can see that you make a post request to https://en.indonetwork.co.id/ajax.

So you can either try to replicate that - see if you can capture the payload sent in the post request from a scrape of the home page and send that.

Or you could use selenium to load the page, click the button, and then capture the data.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need scraping, there is ajax call happening under the hood

```py
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://en.indonetwork.co.id/company/surrama-groups').text)
v = soup.find(class_='btn btn-contact btn-contact-phone btn-contact-ajax').attrs
data_id = v['data-id']
data_text = v['data-text']
data_type = v['data-type']

data = requests.post('https://en.indonetwork.co.id/ajax', json={
    'id': data_id,
    'text': data_text,
    'type': data_type,
    'url': "leads/ajax"
}).json()

mobile_no = re.findall(r'(\d+)', data['text'])
print(mobile_no) #['622122520556', '6287885720277']
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not working with beautifulsoup because it is `not static` site. I mean when you click the `phone` button, it sends the request to api endpoint and then renders the response from that request. You can check this in network tab in dev tools.(I confirmed this)

BeautifulSoup only retrieves the first static html from request. It does not takes account of requests triggered by user interaction.

### Solution of this is `selenium`.

Here are the exact steps you can follow to get this done.

1. Load the selenium with headerful browser.(headerful browser allows you to interact with web page easily)
2. Find the `phone` button and click on it.
3. Wait for some time until request gets processed and has been rendered on screen.
4. Then you can grab the content of the element as per your requirement.

### Not so good solution

You can directly send the request to that exact same api endpoint. But it will have some security barriers like cors to go over from.

This is not good solution because api endpoint might get change or as this api call contains phone number they can make this more secure for future usage. But the interaction on web page nearly remains the same.